# Elixir phoenix where should one put global controller helpers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I need the following functions in almost all controllers. Is there an ApplicationController like module in Elixir?

Where should we put these?

```
  def redirect_if_unauthorized(conn = %Plug.Conn{assigns: %{authorized: false}}, opts) do
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "You can't access that page!")
    |> redirect(to: "/")
    |> halt
  end

  def redirect_if_unauthorized(conn = %Plug.Conn{assigns: %{authorized: true}}, opts), do: conn
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As one way to go, you could create a separate module and import it in the `web.ex` file in the `controller` function.

Like this:

```
defmodule MyApp.Web do

# Some code...

  def controller do
    quote do

      # Some code ...

      import MyApp.CustomFunctions

      # Some code ...

    do
  end

# Some code...

end
```

Comment: Is there a convention about where the module should be located?

Comment: @Chris I am not sure, I guess you can put it wherever you think you should.  Probably in the `web` folder though, so it would be reloaded.

Comment: Ok thanks. I put some code in controllers/helpers and views/helpers for now, seems fine!

Answer (score 5):

Typically these would be inside a Plug, added to your routing pipeline.

This example is used in Programming Phoenix:

- they define a `Rumbl.Auth` module with an `authenticate_user` function
- they include the plug in their router via `import Rumbl.Auth, only: [authenticate_user: 2]`
- they then pipe requests through it - `pipe_through [:browser, :authenticate_user]`.